# SVN "Can't open file '.../db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied" on import

Tags: apache, svn, centos

It has been asked a lot of times here, and none of the answers have worked so far for me.

I'm getting the folowing error on apache error_log

```
could not begin a transaction  [500, #13]

Can't open file '/var/www/svn/repo/db/txn-current-lock': Permission denied  [500, #13]
```

when trying to do

```
svn import -m "Initial" /mnt/logs/ http://localhost/svn/repo/
```

Info on that file:

```
ls -l /var/www/repo/db/txn-current-lock
```

> -rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache 0 abr 20 12:37 /var/www/svn/repo/db/txn-current-lock

I'm running on CentOS 7.2 and I can access `http://localhost/svn/repo` tho there's only this there:

> repo - Revision 0: /

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After fighting with permissions, I decided to just look again at the "howto" and solved the issue. I basically forgot to type:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/svn/repo
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/svn/repo
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Befofre that, you shall do `semanage fcontext -a --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/path/to/your/svn/repo/files(/.*)?'`